# Injecting DbContext into LoggerProvider throws StackOverflowException in .NET Core

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .net core 2.2 with entityframework core. I want to write logs in database using entityframework. So I'm trying to inject DbContext to LoggerProvider.

//Main function

```
new WebHostBuilder().ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
{
    logging.ClearProviders();                                        
    logging.AddDatabase(hostingContext.Configuration);
}).UseStartup<Startup>();
```

//Extension method

```
public static ILoggingBuilder AddDatabase(this ILoggingBuilder builder, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    builder.AddConfiguration();
    builder.Services.AddDbContext<LoggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DevelopmentConnection"), x => x.MigrationsHistoryTable("__LoggingMigrationHistory", "dbo")));
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<ILoggerProvider, DatabaseLoggerProvider>());
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IConfigureOptions<LoggerOptions>, LoggerConfigurationOptions>());
    builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IOptionsChangeTokenSource<LoggerOptions>, LoggerProviderOptionsChangeTokenSource<LoggerOptions, DatabaseLoggerProvider>>());
    return builder;
}
```

//LoggerOptions

```
public class LoggerOptions
{
    public string LogLevel { get; set; }     
}
```

//LoggerConfigurationOptions

```
public class LoggerConfigurationOptions : ConfigureFromConfigurationOptions<LoggerOptions>
{
    public LoggerConfigurationOptions(ILoggerProviderConfiguration<DatabaseLoggerProvider> providerConfiguration) : base(providerConfiguration.Configuration)
    {
    }
}
```

//Logging Context

```
public class LoggingContext : DbContext
{
    public LoggingContext(DbContextOptions<LoggingContext> options) : base(options) //In base constructor exception is thrown
    {
    }
}
```

//Logger Provider

```
[Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ProviderAlias("Database")]
public class DatabaseLoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
{
    public DatabaseLoggerProvider(IOptionsMonitor<LoggerOptions> Settings, LoggingContext context) //I cannot inject context here
    {
    }
}
```

Problem is DbContext constructor throws `StackOverflowException`. Can anyone tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So you inject **context into** the **provider**, but first DI needs to inject the *options into* the *context*, but first DI needs to inject the `provider into` the `options`, but first DI needs to inject the **context into** the **provider**, but first DI needs to inject *options into* the *context**, but first DI needs to inject the `provider into` the `options`...

Comment: @CaiusJard, I see your point. But what is solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever is using LoggingContext should create a new instance, perhaps in constructor or base class constructor.

Comment: Let me clarify more, `DatabaseLoggerProvider` passes context instance to `DatabaseLogger`. Then It is used in `Log` method of `DatabaseLogger`. I cannot inject it to either.